# Neon Chat js send message issue i don;t know how to implement php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this Js file and i want to implement Php request for sending message , history,update but nothing,i'm new with this, please help me.
The chat can be viewed here: http://demo.neontheme.com/extra/chat-api/

Db structure is: id | from | fromOpponent | message | time |unread

The js file:

```
var neonChat = neonChat || {
    $current_user: null,
    isOpen: false,
    chat_history: [],
    statuses: {
        online: {class: 'is-online', order: 1, label: 'Online'},
        offline: {class: 'is-offline', order: 4, label: 'Offline'},
        idle: {class: 'is-idle', order: 3, label: 'Idle'},
        busy: {class: 'is-busy', order: 2, label: 'Busy'}
    }
};

;(function($, window, undefined)
{
    "use strict";

    var $chat = $("#chat"),
        $chat_inner = $chat.find('.chat-inner'),
        $chat_badge = $chat.find('.badge').add($('.chat-notifications-badge')),
        $conversation_window = $chat.find(".chat-conversation"),
        $conversation_header = $conversation_window.find(".conversation-header"),
        $conversation_body = $conversation_window.find('.conversation-body'),
        $textarea = $conversation_window.find('.chat-textarea textarea'),

        sidebar_default_is_open = ! $(".page-container").hasClass('sidebar-collapsed');


    $.extend(neonChat, {    

        init: function()
        {
            // Conversation Close
            $conversation_window.on('click', '.conversation-close', neonChat.close);

            $("body").on('click', '.chat-close', function(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();

                var animate = $(this).is('[data-animate]');

                neonChat.hideChat(animate);
            });

            $("body").on('click', '.chat-open', function(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();

                var animate = $(this).is('[data-animate]');

                neonChat.showChat(animate);
            });


            // Texarea
            $textarea.keydown(function(e)
            {
                if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    neonChat.submitMessage();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                if(e.keyCode == 27)
                {
                    neonChat.close();
                }
            });


            $chat.on('click', '.chat-group a', function(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();

                var $chat_user = $(this);

                if($chat_user.hasClass('active'))
                {
                    neonChat.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    neonChat.open($chat_user);
                }
            });

            $chat.find('.chat-group a').each(function(i, el)
            {
                var $this = $(el);

                $this.append('<span class="badge badge-info is-hidden">0</span>');
            });

            neonChat.refreshUserIds();
            neonChat.orderGroups();
            neonChat.prefetchMessages();
            neonChat.countUnreadMessages();
            neonChat.puffUnreads();

            // Chat
            if($chat.hasClass('fixed') && $chat_inner.length && $.isFunction($.fn.niceScroll))
            {
                $chat.find('.chat-inner').niceScroll({
                    cursorcolor: '#454a54',
                    cursorborder: '1px solid #454a54',
                    railpadding: {right: 3},
                    railalign: 'right',
                    cursorborderradius: 1
                });
            }

            // Chat Toggle
            $("body").on('click', '[data-toggle="chat"]', function(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();

                var $this = $(this),
                    with_animation = $this.is('[data-animate]'),
                    collapse_sidebar = $this.is('[data-collapse-sidebar]');

                neonChat.toggleChat(with_animation, collapse_sidebar);
            });
        },      
        updateConversationOffset: function($el)
        {
            var top_h = $conversation_window.find('.conversation-body').position().top + 1,
                offset = $el.position().top - top_h,
                minus = 0,

                con_h = $conversation_window.height(),
                win_h = $(window).height();

            if($chat.hasClass('fixed') && offset + con_h > win_h)
            {
                minus = offset + con_h - win_h;
            }

            if($(".page-container.horizontal-menu").length)
            {
                minus += $(".page-container.horizontal-menu .navbar").height();
            }

            offset -= minus;

            $conversation_window.transition({
                top: offset,
                opacity: 1
            });

        },

        getChatHistoryLength: function()
        {
            var max_chat_history = parseInt($chat.data('max-chat-history'), 10);

            if( ! max_chat_history || max_chat_history < 1)
            {
                max_chat_history = 25;
            }

            return max_chat_history;

        },

        submitMessage: function() // Submit whats on textarea
        {
            var msg = $.trim($textarea.val());

            $textarea.val('');

            if(this.isOpen && this.$current_user)
            {
                var id = this.$current_user.uniqueId().attr('id');

                this.pushMessage(id, msg.replace( /<.*?>/g, '' ), $chat.data('current-user'), new Date());
                this.renderMessages(id);
            }
        },

        refreshUserIds: function()
        {
            $('#chat .chat-group a').each(function(i, el)
            {
                var $this = $(el),
                    $status = $this.find('.user-status');

                $this.uniqueId();

                var id = $this.attr('id');

                if(typeof neonChat.chat_history[id] == 'undefined')
                {
                    var status = $this.data('status');

                    if( ! status)
                    {
                        for(var i in neonChat.statuses)
                        {
                            if($status.hasClass(neonChat.statuses[i].class))
                            {
                                status = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    neonChat.chat_history[id] = {
                        $el: $this,
                        messages: [],
                        unreads: 0,
                        status: status
                    };
                }
            });

        },

        pushMessage: function(id, msg, from, time, fromOpponent, unread)
        {
            if(id && msg)
            {
                this.refreshUserIds();

                var max_chat_history = this.getChatHistoryLength();

                if(this.chat_history[id].messages.length >= max_chat_history)
                {
                    this.chat_history[id].messages = this.chat_history[id].messages.reverse().slice(0, max_chat_history - 1).reverse();
                }


                this.chat_history[id].messages.push({
                    message: msg,
                    from: from,
                    time: time,
                    fromOpponent: fromOpponent,
                    unread: unread
                });

                if(unread)
                {
                    this.puffUnreadsAll();
                }

                this.puffUnreads();
            }
        },

        renderMessages: function(id, slient)
        {
            if(typeof this.chat_history[id] != 'undefined')
            {
                $conversation_body.html('');

                for(var i in this.chat_history[id].messages)
                {
                    var entry = this.chat_history[id].messages[i],
                        $entry = $('<li><span class="user"></span><p></p><span class="time"></span></li>'),
                        date = entry.time,
                        date_formated = date;

                    if(typeof date == 'object')
                    {
                        var hour = date.getHours(),
                            hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour,

                            min  = date.getMinutes(),
                            min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min,

                            sec  = date.getSeconds();
                            sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;

                        date_formated = hour + ':' + min;
                    }

                    // Populate message DOM
                    $entry.find('.user').html(entry.from);
                    $entry.find('p').html(entry.message.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
                    $entry.find('.time').html(date_formated);

                    if(entry.fromOpponent)
                    {
                        $entry.addClass('odd');
                    }

                    if(entry.unread && typeof slient == 'undefined')
                    {
                        $entry.addClass('unread');
                        entry.unread = false;
                    }

                    $conversation_body.append($entry);
                }

                this.updateScrollbars();
            }
        },

        prefetchMessages: function()
        {
            $chat.find('.chat-group a').each(function(i, el)
            {
                var $contact = $(el),
                    id = $contact.attr('id'),
                    history_container = $contact.data('conversation-history');

                if(history_container && history_container.length)
                {
                    $($(history_container)).find('> li').each(function(j, el2)
                    {
                        var $entry = $(el2),
                            from = $entry.find('.user').html(),
                            message = $entry.find('p').html(),
                            time = $entry.find('.time').html(),
                            fromOpponent = $entry.hasClass('even') || $entry.hasClass('odd') || $entry.hasClass('opponent'),
                            unread = $entry.hasClass('unread');

                        neonChat.pushMessage(id, message, from, time, fromOpponent, unread)
                    });
                }

            });
        },



    // Set Cursor
    $conversation_body.on('click', function()
    {
        $textarea.focus();
    });


    // Refresh Ids
    neonChat.init();

})(jQuery, window);
```

What i have trying to implement but failed:

```
function sendChat(id, msg, from, time, fromOpponent, unread) { 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {'function': 'from','message': message,'fromOpponent': id,'unread': unread},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
```

The Php/Html code:

```
<div id="chat" class="fixed" data-current-user="<?php echo $user->filter->username;?>" data-order-by-status="1" data-max-chat-history="25">

            <?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testest', 'user', 'pass');
    $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM `mls_users`";               
    $userz = $conn->query($sqlb);
    foreach ($userz as $row) {   
        $name= $row['name'];
        $surename = $row['surename'];
        $status = $row['statusonline'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<a href='#' data-conversation-history='#sample_history_".$id."' id='$id'><span class='user-status is-".$status."line'></span> <em>$name $surename</em></a>";
} 

?>
        </div>


    <!-- conversation template -->
    <div class="chat-conversation">

        <div class="conversation-header">
            <a href="#" class="conversation-close"><i class="entypo-cancel"></i></a>

            <span class="user-status"></span>
            <span class="display-name"></span> 
            <small></small>
        </div>

        <ul class="conversation-body">  
        </ul>

        <div class="chat-textarea">
            <textarea class="form-control autogrow" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
     <?php
     $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chat', 'user', 'pass');
     $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM `messages` "; 
     $userr = $con->query($sqlb);   
     foreach ($userr as $row) {   

        $from= $row['from'];
        $fromOpponent = $row['fromOpponent']; 
        }  
     ?>
<!-- Chat Histories -->
 <?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chat', 'user', 'pass');
    $sqlb = "SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i') as `time`,`id`,`name`,`surename`,`message`,`unread`,`from`,`fromOpponent` FROM `message` WHERE `from`='$from' AND `fromOpponent`='$fromOpponent'";               
    $userz = $conn->query($sqlb);

    foreach ($userz as $row) {
        $id =  $row['id'];
        $from= $row['from'];
        $fromOpponent= $row['fromOpponent'];
        $name= $row['name'];
        $surename= $row['surname'];
        $message = $row['messagee'];
        $time= $row['time']; 
        $unread = $row['unread'];

        echo "<ul class='chat-history' id='sample_history_$from'>
        <li class='opponent $unread'>
        <span class='user'>$name $surename</span>
        <p>$message</p>
        <span class='time'>$time</span>";
}
?>
</li>
</ul>   
    </div>
```

Comment: the `sendChat` function has a parameter `msg` but in the function body when you send data you reference a variable `message` - also, a few of the other parameters in the function definition are not used

Comment: Thanks for reply but can u help me please? i spend hrs to find a solution but nothing, here is my last hope , here are good people.